# facebook api php post images to timeline

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post image with message to timeline, Problem is that i can post images to '/me/photos' but i want to post it to '/me/feed' when i try doing this i am getting error:'(#100)source should have valid url' but using same URL it is getting posted to me/photos. I am attaching the local image from HTML form. Below is code i am using

```
$message = hello;

$selectedImage = '/path-to-image/img.jpg';

$postData = array(

 'message' => $message,

 'source'  => $facebook->fileToUpload($selectedImage));

 $request = $facebook->post('/me/feed',$postData);
```

Using facebook-graph-api-v2.9.

Comment: You can not just post a photo to the feed endpoint, only if you post a link you could specify a thumbnail for that link. (Could, because now even that is not possible any more dynamically at the time of sharing, see the duplicate.)

Comment: Thank you @CBroe ...i also want to know whether we can post message, link, image, video all together in single post?

Comment: You can post a link, that has a video attached and a thumbnail set via Open Graph meta tags.